# YouTube iframe embed does not show controls when controls=1

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

This is what my iframe looks like:

```
<iframe title="Youtube video player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3gl8S1erh04?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=1&amp;rel=0&amp;playlist=3gl8S1erh04" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```

The query parameters are: `?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=1&amp;rel=0&amp;playlist=3gl8S1erh04`

I need the video muted, but want to show the controls to allow the user to unmute. Except `controls=1` doesn't seem to show the controls. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange. I tested your code on jsfiddle and I see the controls - [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHMmM.png) - can you share the current results in a screenshot?

Comment: It's our setup. Our CSS intentionally hid the controls and I didn't realize it. Thanks for helping, though.